# All Files, Master Pages, Page Layouts disappeared from SP Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer

All Files, Master Pages, Page Layouts disappeared from SP Designer. Publishing feature for the site collection is activated and the user that I'm login is system administrator.

They all suddenly disappeared. How can I make them appear again?

Thanks.

Comment: Close the SPD and open it again.

Comment: did you checked with refresh button on ribbon ?

Comment: Closing SPD and opening again didn't work but refresh button worked! :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refresh the SPD from the top ribbon.

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it solves problem.

Comment: Sorry. I just saw this.